# Непонятен принцип работы шаблонных функций

Tags: c++

Во время продвижения в своем обучении программированию плавно подошел к теме шаблонных функций.

> С помощью шаблона функции можно определить алгоритм, который будет
>   применяться к данным различных типов...

- Объясните мне пожалуйста, зачем при указании названия функции
  необходимо указывать еще и тип этой функции(например`template <class
  type>`**`void`**`sort(){...}`). Разве `template <class type>` не
  выполняет роль типа функции?
- Тип формальных параметров функции определяется исходя из того, какие типы мы задаем самостоятельно. Тогда о каких данных
  различных типов идет речь в цитате, приведенной из книге, по которой
  я занимаюсь?

Очень буду рад развернутым ответам, желательно с примерами. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 10):

> Тип формальных параметров функции определяется исходя из того, какие типы мы задаем самостоятельно. Тогда о каких данных различных типов идет речь в цитате, приведенной из книге, по которой я занимаюсь?

Вы пишите обобщенный код, например:

```
template <typename T>
T mul(T lv, T rv) {
   return (lv * rv);
}
```

, требуя, чтобы для типа Т была определена операция *, иначе - ошибка компиляции.

При вызове данной функции с доменами разных типов, например так:

```
mul(12, 22);        // но не mul<int>(12, 22)
mul<short>(12, 22); // [1] а вдруг ?)  
mul(12.0, 22.0)     // но не mul<float>(...)
```

тип выведется автоматически, тип указывать не следует если на то нет явной причины[1].

Как это сделать проще (-std=c++11):

```
template <typename T>
auto mul(T lv, T rv) -> decltype(T * T) {
   return (lv * rv);
}
```

Как это сделать проще (-std=c++14):

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) mul(T lv, T rv) {
   return (lv * rv);
}
```

В данном контексте - неявное преимущество. Давайте посмотрим на следующий пример:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
? mul(T lv, U rv) {
    return (lv * rv);
}
```

Что будем выводить? T? U? :)

---

Про вывод типов хорошо написано у Мейерса в книге [Эффективный и современный C++](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34747131/)

> Объясните мне пожалуйста, зачем при указании названия функции необходимо указывать еще и тип этой функции(напримерtemplate  **void** sort(){...}). Разве template  не выполняет роль типа функции?

Чтобы работал вывод типов )))

<s>P.S. Как-то режет слух это выражение - "тип функции", сразу в воздухе чувствуется запах Haskell'a с `Type -> Type` ... Наверное, лучше употреблять термины вроде тип возвращаемого значения, типы параметров и т.д.</s>

> Объясните мне пожалуйста, зачем при указании названия функции необходимо указывать еще и тип этой функции(напримерtemplate  **void** sort(){...}). Разве template  не выполняет роль типа функции?

Не всегда параметры типа - *типы*, например:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t array_size(T(&)[N]) noexcept { 
    return N; 
}
```

Как видите, T понадобился только для того, чтобы вывести тип параметра функции, в теле же функции - ни одного упоминания.

**FIX.:**

```
template <typename T>
auto mul(T lv, T rv) -> decltype(/* T * T */ lv * rv) {
   return (lv * rv);
}
```

Comment: все хорошо изложено, но  выражение "тип функции" вполне нормальное: ведь первая ваша функция имеет тип  T(T, T)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, если это так, то мне стыдно - я не знал, что так можно говорить :) Спасибо, что поправили!

Comment: А зачем скобки вокруг `lv * rv`?

Comment: @dIm0n, где именно?

Comment: @isnullxbh в ретурне `return (lv * rv);`

Comment: @dIm0n, так, хорошо. А что с ними не так?

Comment: @isnullxbh ничего, просто спрашиваю зачем они стоят там, а в `return N;` не стоят

Comment: @dIm0n, это дело вкуса, в данном случае это роли не играет.

Answer (score 6):

> Объясните мне пожалуйста, зачем при указании названия функции необходимо указывать еще и тип этой функции

Вы хотели сказать **тип возвращаемого значения** (у вас это `void`). Вообще-то для функций его **всегда** нужно указывать, этот случай не исключение.

`template <class type>` указывает, что следующее далее определение зависит от типа, который в определении обозначен как `type`, но **как именно** зависит, не предписывает: будет ли `type` в типах аргументов, типе возвращаемого значения, в типе локальной переменной в теле функции, нескольких местах или не будет вовсе (такое тоже возможно).

> Тип формальных параметров функции определяется исходя из того, какие типы мы задаем самостоятельно. Тогда о каких данных различных типов идет речь в цитате, приведенной из книге, по которой я занимаюсь?

Шаблонная функция сама по себе ещё не функция, у неё неполное определение. Эта неполнота ограничивается как раз параметрами шаблона, в вашем случае единственным типом `type`. Для разных наборов параметров (у вас — для разных типов) этот шаблон создаст ("инстанцирует") **различные функции**. А не одну-единственную.

В совокупности один и тот же алгоритм действительно применяется с разными типами, но происходит это **в разных функциях**.

Answer (score 5):

> Разве `template <class type>` не  выполняет роль типа функции?

Нет, оно является частью объявления шаблона, а не объявления функции. Тип возвращаемого значения в примере — `void`.

> Тогда о каких данных различных типов идет речь в цитате, приведенной из книге, по которой я занимаюсь?

Достаточно немного усложнить пример и фраза из книги сразу станет очевидна:

```
template <class Type>
void sort_des(Type *arr, size_t sz) {
  for (size_t i=0; i<sz-1; i++) {
    size_t max_n = i;
    for (size_t j=i+1; j<sz; j++) {
      if (arr[max_n] < arr[j]) {
        max_n = j;
      }
    }
    Type tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[max_n];
    arr[max_n] = tmp;
  }
}
```

В итоге эта функция будет сортировать по убыванию простым выбором Си'шный массив любого типа.

```
constexpr size_t arrSz = 1024;
int iArr[arrSz];
double dArr[arrSz];

// ... Заполнение массивов

sort_des(iArr, arrSz);
sort_des(dArr, arrSz);
```

Причём в данном случае компилятор сам определит тип инстанцируемого шаблона по аргументам.

Comment: а также вопрос возник , скорее всего , по причине плохого качества учебника или невнимательного чтения

Answer (score 3):

Ну а если я напишу такой простой пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
template < class tp >
void f()
{
    cout << typeid(tp).hash_code();
}

int main()
{    
    f<int>();
    f<string>();
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Что вы тогда скажете?..

Тут функция имеет тип не возвращаюший ничего и не имеющий аргумент. Аргумент шаблона может выражать любую абстракцию, в том числе и тип возврата функции и тип аргументов функции и не иметь отношения ни к аргументам функции, ни к возвращающему типу.

Не путайте инстанцирование шаблона по типу аргумента функции с  типом функции. Компилятор не должен вместо вас решать что вы хотите получить в результате выполнения функции и какие аргументы вы хотите ей передать, а шаблонная функция определяется во время компиляции.   Может кто то другой обьяснит получше. Я в этом плане не спец, но надеюсь вы кое что понели...